# Can I use scanf to require that a certain string appears next in the input?

Tags: c, scanf

I want to parse a file format that looks like this:

```
SECTION Foo
10
END
```

I tried using the following code to do the parsing. It should return 1 in case of a parsing error:

```
int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int n;

    int nr1 = scanf("SECTION %s", str);
    if (nr1 != 1) return 1;

    int nr2 = scanf("%d", &n);
    if (nr2 != 1) return 1;

    int nr3 = scanf("END");
    if (nr3 != 0) return 1;

    printf("OK! %s %d\n", str, n);
    return 0;
}
```

However, the `OK!` message shows up even before I type `END` in the standard input. What I actually want is to detect if the next string that appears in stdin is `END` and return with an error code otherwise. Is there a way that I can modify the `scanf("END")` line to achieve this?

Right now, the only way I can think is to use a `%s` scanf followed by a `strcmp` but it seems inelegant to have to introduce extra temporary variables just for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `scanf()` for this, because it returns the number of tokens parsed, which when there are no tokens to parse means you can't tell success from failure.

This is not a big deal, because using `scanf()` for parsing is not a good idea anyway.  Instead, you should simply tokenize your file (in your case, by newlines then whitespace), and analyze the tokens.  This means using `fgets()`, `strcmp()`, `sscanf()`, `strtol()`, etc.

Or use a parser generator like ANTLR.

Answer (score 4):

To use `scanf()` and determine if it scanned as desired *after* the last directives (even with 0 specifiers), use `"%n"`.  This records the offset of the scan - if the scan ever reached that point.

```
int n = 0;
scanf("END%n", &n);
if (n > 0) {
  // Scan made it past "END"
  Success();
} else {
  Failure();
}
```

Still better to read a *line* with `fgets()` and then parse/scan the string.  Using `scanf()` is challenging to cope with unexpected input.

---

Note that `scanf("SECTION %s", str);` lacks width limitation.
Suggest `int nr1 = scanf("SECTION %99s", str);`